# Synchronized Adventure

Tags: java, synchronized

If i come across a situation where i will have to make each and every method in my Java program **synchronized**, will that affect the performance of my code?

Comment: Please try searching for an answer first. This question is very generic and can be answered with general theory available for free all over the internet, including from Oracle directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will influence the performance.

If your application is mostly single-threaded, then the impact will be very small, because uncontested lock acquisition is very fast (on modern JVMs such as HotSpot).

If your application is heavily multi-threaded **and** multiple threads access the same objects concurrently, then the impact will be larger.

Note that having every single method synchronized does **not** guarantee that your code is thread-safe, you can still easily get race conditions.